# create iPad app with realistic background images

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app with a regular, drab-looking UISplitView. I would like to enhance the visuals to make it look cutting-edge, by adding realistic backgrounds (like faux-wood). I'm looking at this app as an example:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/to-do/id413879773?mt=8

They seem to use 2 regular UITableView's next to each other inside a SplitView. But I can't figure out:
a) how to create the offset for the 2 tableviews so that the leather background covers them all-around
b) how to create the splitView so that there's space left for a toolbar at the bottom
c) are the flaps on the side another tableView inside the DetailView's view? (i.e. the detail view has 2 tableviews inside it)?

Would love some help deconstructing a design like this. Here's another great example:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/todo-for-ipad/id371787147?mt=8